# Subtract current row value by previous row value and get balance amount to current row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I need to get the `balanceAmount` by subtracting the current row value from the previous row's value. Expected result is as below.

[image: expected result]

Here is my current query

```
select 
    pp.*,
    pp.topupAmount - sum(pp.chargeAmount) over (over by pp.ROW_NUM rows unbounded preceding) AS balanceAmount
from 
    (select 
         row_number() over (order by ppc.sortDate) ROW_NUM, ppc.*
     from 
         (select 0 as topupAmount, t1.chargeAmount, t1.sortDate  
          from t1
          union all
          select t2.topupAmount, 0 as chargeAmount, t2.sortDate   
          from t2) as ppc
     ) as pp    
order by 
    pp.ROW_NUM
```

This is what I am getting from above query

[image: current result]

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select
    t.*,
    sum(topupAmount - chargeAmount) over(order by row_num) balanceAmount
from mytable t
```

Actually by looking at your query it seems like `row_num` is a generated column, so you likely want:

```
select
    t.*,
    sum(topupAmount - chargeAmount) over(order by sortDate) balanceAmount
from mytable t
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. `sum(topupAmount - chargeAmount) over (order by row_num) balanceAmount` worked. `sum(topupAmount - chargeAmount) over(order by sortDate) balanceAmount` gave wrong balance `(500.00, 495.00, 487.50, 487.50, 482.50, 467.50, 467.50, 467.50)`

Answer (score 1):

You need window function :

```
select t.*, sum(topupAmount - chargeAmount) over (order by sortDate) as balanceAmount
from table t;
```